# Android - PHP $_FILES Parameters?

Tags: php, android

How can I use the Following PHP code alongside a HTTPPost Request sent from my Android Application:

```
<?php
  $file_path = "userimage/";
  $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
   echo "success";
  } else {
   echo "fail";
  }
?>
```

Can I simply do this:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uploaded_file", encoded));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tmp_name", "testImage.jpg"));
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("URL TO PHP");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I am confused as to why the PHP code contains name, uploaded_file and tmp_name and Where do they come from Exaclty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data structure of uploaded file depends on the implementation in the PHP language. Please refer to the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Your *$_FILES['uploaded_file']* is an array of information about uploaded file:

**$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']**
The original name of the file on the client machine.

**$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']**
The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.

**$_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']**
The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

try set enctype = multipart/form-data